# Java filename searching

Tags: java, database, file, filenames, flat-file

I need to make a database for book storing. So what I want to do Is basically make a file for each book which I have done.

Now I need to search books when I need them. In 2 functions I'll need to find the book and edit its information.

I have no idea how to get the name of a file and assign it to a scanner\bufferwriter\ect.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using a RDBMS or flat files?

Comment: Just .txt files, I put them in C://"program_name" (don't have a name yet)

Comment: Your question is too broad. However, you have clearly identified where the gap is in your knowledge, where you said *I have no idea how to get the name of a file and assign it to a scanner\bufferwriter\ect*, which is a great starting point. Split that up in to two concerns: getting the name of a file(s), and writing to / reading from text files. That should be where your research begins. Write some prototype programs to text what you find, and then put it all together and write the main program. Post back when you've encountered a question or problem that hasn't already been answered here.

Comment: I know how to write to a file with a constand name. but what if I were to change thet name. I'd need to put it in a variable. the only problem so far is how to find the file with the name I'm looking for. Is there a statement that returns the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Put the names of the files into another, known filename (ie: BookList.txt) and then when your program opens you can parse through this file and get the other file names in the directory.
2. You can get the file directory listing and store it into a list. For example:

   ```
   File f = new File("C:\\");
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));
   ```

Once you know the file names, you can open these files and make any necessary edits. Don't forget to also close your file readers and writers once you're done with them!

You can iterate through the array using a for loop. For example:

```
for(String i : names){ // iterate through each file name in the array
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(i);

    ... // do some parsing

    fileScanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Does this mean there is no real statement for getting filenames bcause I tried what you did there and it messed up a bit that's why I'm here

Comment: @MySecAccCodeMast See [File list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) method.

Comment: for some reason I can't make an array of strings

Comment: For future reference, please post code as [SCCE](http://sscce.org/) in your original post. Where do you attempt to use the File list method?

Comment: at searchbook to show all info about a book of choise and at reservements to change the reservment and the date

Comment: Simply make the ArrayList of strings in your ```searchbook``` method. Iterate through the list using a for loop. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks i'll poste the methode when I'm done. How about the other methode

Comment: Please go through the API and find tutorials on specific questions or open a new question. I cannot go through your entire code for you.

Comment: Still got a problem:the secopnd next() does not work, the one for codes this is the code: http://pastebin.com/5cEU9hLW

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Please go through the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) API. Also go through some tutorials on file reading and writing. You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716503/2557554) helpful.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't count up to the problem because it seems right to me... can you see whats wrong